# Change in user domain using curl

Tags: command-line, server, apache2

When I enter the command:

```
$curl -basic https://www.google.com$
```

The output I receive is simply the text for the html page that we see when we visit the website.

but when I execute:

```
$curl -basic https://www.yahoo.com$
```

I receive no output, and the domain in my terminal changes from `username@computer_name` to `Regional Redirectusername@computername`.

What does this mean?  I'm just not comfortable with that seeing I had thought what I was doing was sending a request to receive the text based content on the index page for a www domain. I apologize if this question is too vague, but I'd definitely like to know what the difference is here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You need always get HTML result I recommend use using curl flag "-L":

```
curl -L yahoo.com
```

or

```
curl -L https://www.yahoo.com
```

This flag force curl follow all URL redirects (graphical browser behavior). In case when site will redirect you couple of times, for example, to regional version, you always have chance get final HTML.

From curl man:

**-L, --location**

> (HTTP) If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a
>   3XX
>                 response  code),  this  option  will make curl redo the request on the new place. If used together with -i, --include or -I,
>   --head,
>                 headers from all requested pages will be shown. When authentication is used, curl only sends its credentials to the initial
>   host. If
>                 a  redirect  takes  curl to a different host, it won't be able to intercept the user+password. See also --location-trusted on
>   how to
>                 change this. You can limit the amount of redirects to follow by using the --max-redirs option.
>
> When curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain GET (for example POST or PUT), it will do the following request 
>   with  a
>                 GET  if the HTTP response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response code was any other 3xx code, curl will re-send the following
>   request
>                 using the same unmodified method.
>
> You can tell curl to not change the non-GET request method to GET after a 30x response by using  the  dedicated  options 
>   for  that:
>                 --post301, --post302 and --post303.

Comment: Thanks curl -L https://www.yahoo.com returns the full HTML output

Answer (score 2):

You should know that when you add the option `-basic` you actually set multiple parameters. What you might have wanted to do is `--basic` for basic authentication. Also the final `$` sign is probably a typo.

If you execute the following, do you get the same unexpected behavior?

`curl https://www.yahoo.com`

Comment: Yeah the same thing occurs with out -basic appended

Comment: And the same when I append --basic